# Online payment solutions other than Paypal?

Tags: ecommerce, online-payment

I am looking for a payment solution to handle payments on a website.

**Criteria:**

- **Not Paypal**: [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/us/home) is obviously a candidate, but I want to see what alternatives are out there
- **Works on custom-built website**: can't use solutions such as [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) for instance.
- **Not integrated**: clicking on the payment button should bring users to the payment solution's website where transactions are handled. This rules out  [integrated solutions like Stripe](https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/) where users have to fill in their payment details on your website (the website being too low profile to create enough trust for people to do so).
- **Low volume**: there will be a dozen of transactions per week, so can't use enterprise solutions such as [Adyen](https://www.adyen.com/) which require a minimum turnover.
- **Not country-specific**: the solution should handle payments from [top e-commerce countries](https://www.emarketer.com/Chart/Top-25-Countries-Ranked-by-Retail-Ecommerce-Sales-2015-2020-billions/203438) (countries from which I can expect buyers), which rules out solutions like [Amazon Pay](https://pay.amazon.com/us/shopper) which isn't present in some e-commerce markets from which I expect sales (Brazil, Netherlands, Sweden...)

**Any idea what solution I could use other than Paypal?**

Comment: So basically you're not looking for software – but a payment service you can link to?

Comment: Yes, which, as I am answering this question makes me realize this Q&A site might not be the right place to ask :) (although that payment service is software itself)

Comment: That's what I was pointing at, yes. As long as you only want to "link there" (quote: "not integrated"), it's not software (API, library, module) you request but a "payment company" (bank, financial institute) offering such. Thus I'm tempted to close-vote it as off-topic – but being a mod that would mean swinging the hammer (having immediate effect). Not being 100% sure on which site of the "border line" this is, I thus rather leave it to the community. Good luck with it, though – and thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That's why it's called "[Izzy going](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Easy%20going)" – and not "Izzy [has left the building](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=has%20left%20the%20building)" :)

Answer (score 2):

From what you have suggested I would maybe look at the following:

- **Stripe** - This has an easy sign-up process and hosted payment options to reduce the PCI compliance issues and ideal for low volume. It's also very popular so there are a number of integrations avilable for it.
- **Braintree Payments** - A little like stripe, maybe aimed at higher volume, but not as much as Adyen.

You could also consider options such as the following which sit in between a payment gateway and your site and allow you to switch gateways whenever you feel like it and offer hosted pages. (I've used both of these following two in the past and have found both to be good.)

- **Recurly** - Very robust, has a good selection of gateways and even has its own gateway option if you are in the US. Has functionality to help calculate VAT along with very good support.
- **Chargify** - Very similar to the above, but doesn't have it's own gateway and slightly different functionality.

A final option could be:

- **Wufoo** - I've never used this option, but from what I understand they allow you to integrate your payment gateway into them as with the above two and them you use their hosted forms, but may be a lot cheaper and suitable for lower volume than recurly and chargify. The list of providers that you can integrate with them are shown at https://www.wufoo.com/payments/payment-gateway-comparison/ and there is a good comparison there.

Again the benefit of using a 3rd party is that they usually allow you to switch gateways and a click of a button.

Comment: thanks, does stripe have their own hosted checkout I can just link to? See bullet point 3 `"Not integrated"` as reason why I don't want to use their embedded solution.

Comment: The best they have is https://stripe.com/checkout , if you wanted a hosted page then look at also using Wufoo with stripe and this will achieve what you require.

Comment: The problem is that the checkout is integrated into your website (`"Checkout is an embeddable payment form "`), which is the opposite of what I want: once again, small website nobody knows, I'm afraid it's going to be a conversion killer if people have to give their C/C details on my website (vs. having to give them to Paypal for instance via a Paypal-hosted checkout). Thanks for your input, I'll keep looking, maybe I resort to using Paypal if there's nothing better that fits my needs.